# How to find a string in a column using a list of patterns and add the matched pattern to the same row in next column

Tags: r, regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a data frame with RNASeq samples, gene symbol and expression data. I want to group them according to the sample category.

```
Sample             Gene     Exp 
---------------------------------
A.56.100e.ax       prk1     3.56
A.100CAS.500e.er   prk1    45.20 
A.300.EFE1.cx      prk1     0.21
A.56.100e.ax       csk     51.50
A.100CAS.500e.er   csk    321.47 
A.300.EFE1.cx      csk    186.78
```

What I wanted to do is to add a category in a separate column as follows,

```
Sample             Gene     Exp    Category
-------------------------------------------
A.56.100e.ax       prk1     3.56   A.56
A.100CAS.500e.er   prk1    45.20   A.100CAS
A.300.EFE1.cx      prk1     0.21   A.300
A.56.100e.ax       csk     51.50   A.56
A.100CAS.500e.er   csk    321.47   A.100CAS
A.300.EFE1.cx      csk    186.78   A.300
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture a character followed by a number.

```
df$Category <- sub('([A-Z]\\..*?)\\..*', '\\1', df$Sample)
df

#            Sample Gene    Exp Category
#1     A.56.100e.ax prk1   3.56     A.56
#2 A.100CAS.500e.er prk1  45.20 A.100CAS
#3    A.300.EFE1.cx prk1   0.21    A.300
#4     A.56.100e.ax  csk  51.50     A.56
#5 A.100CAS.500e.er  csk 321.47 A.100CAS
#6    A.300.EFE1.cx  csk 186.78    A.300
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), 
    .Label = c("A.100CAS.500e.er", "A.300.EFE1.cx", "A.56.100e.ax"), 
    class = "factor"), Gene = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
    .Label = c("csk", "prk1"), class = "factor"), 
     Exp = c(3.56, 45.2, 0.21, 51.5, 321.47, 186.78)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Hey guys, I was trying both the answers and found out that there were some samples that contain letters after numbers (ex: A.100CAS). So, that makes it complex. I tried to work around using both of your solutions and found a solution. 

df$Category <- sub("(\\w+\\.\\w+)\\..*", "\\1",df$Sample)

Comment: @RusiruHemage I have updated the answer for your new data.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_remove` to match the `.` followed by one or more characters that are not a `.` till the end (`$`) of the string

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Category = str_remove(Sample, "\\.[^.]+$"))
```

---

With `base R`

```
df$Category <- sub("\\.[^.]+$", "", df1$Sample)
```

Comment: Hey guys, I was trying both the answers and found out that there were some samples that contain letters after numbers (ex: A.100CAS). So, that makes it complex. I tried to work around using both of your solutions and found a solution.

Comment: @RusiruHemage this is a bit hard esp when you posted a question with that pattern and then changed it and somebody come up with a tweaked solution.